# Input Single Value, store 5 different value

Tags: macros

My LaTeX code is:

```
\documentclass{thesis}
\begin{document}
\arttype{5}
\end{document}
```

Required Output is:

If `arttype` value is `5`:

```
`5thArticle Title-tnins` is need to store in \newcommand `\arttext`.
`5thArticle Short Title-tnins` is need to store in newcommand `\artshortname`.
`5thArticle Sub-Title-tnins` is need to store in newcommand `\artabbrtext`.
`5thArticle Color X-tnins` is need to store in newcommand `\artcolor`.
`5thArticle Misc. Value-tnins` is need to store in newcommand `\artmisc`.
```

If `arttype` value is `8`.

```
`8thArticle Title-toins` is need to store in \newcommand `\arttext`.
`8thArticle Short Title-toins` is need to store in newcommand `\artshortname`.
`8thArticle Sub-Title-toins` is need to store in newcommand `\artabbrtext`.
`8thArticle Color X-toins` is need to store in newcommand `\artcolor`.
`8thArticle Misc. Value-toins` is need to store in newcommand `\artmisc`.
```

`arttype` value is `n` number of times. I will print the each `\art*` values in each paragraph separately. How do control in LaTeX class file?

Comment: On the surface, it appears you would like the output "5th" as a string.  On the other hand, perhaps you mean to signify elements of an array, in which, for example, "5thArticle Title" is some arbitrary string associated with the 5th element of the array.  Perhaps a clarification would help.  And if the latter, how do you propose to make these array values available to the document?

Comment: @Steven: I have updated the questions and 5th element is not a fixed value. In the latter i will print each array values in separate places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`arrayjobx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/arrayjobx) can help with such things. Perhaps this is what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/arrayjobx
\makeatletter
\newarray\arttext@aux\readarray{arttext@aux}{A1 & A2 & A3 & A4 & A5 & A6}
\newarray\artshortname@aux\readarray{artshortname@aux}{B1 & B2 & B3 & B4 & B5 & B6}
\newarray\artabbrtext@aux\readarray{artabbrtext@aux}{C1 & C2 & C3 & C4 & C5 & C6}
\newarray\artcolor@aux\readarray{artcolor@aux}{D1 & D2 & D3 & D4 & D5 & D6}
\newarray\artmisc@aux\readarray{artmisc@aux}{E1 & E2 & E3 & E4 & E5 & E6}
\newcommand{\arttype}[1]{% \arttype{<num>}
  \def\arttext{\arrayx{arttext@aux}(#1)}%
  \def\artshortname{\arrayx{artshortname@aux}(#1)}%
  \def\artabbrtext{\arrayx{artabbrtext@aux}(#1)}%
  \def\artcolor{\arracyx{artcolor@aux}(#1)}%
  \def\artmisc{\arrayx{artmisc@aux}(#1)}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\arttype{5}\arttext\ \artmisc

\arttype{2}\arttext\ \artmisc
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is easy work, but i have to store the value in `variable`  and print to any other place (like `\artcolor` value should print each `cross-link`). No need to create any `newcommand`. How do achieve this?

Comment: @Balaji: I have no idea what you mean here, sorry.

Comment: If I give `\arttype{2}` in LaTeX, the value of `\artmisc{E2}` only is like to display before `\thebibliography`. Not like to create any additional `\newcommand` or `\def`.

Comment: @Balaji: Could you include these details as part of your question, making it clear in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)? I still don't understand why with `\arttype{2}` you *only* mention `\artmisc{E2}` when your original post lists a host of possible outputs. Also, should I interpret that `\arttype{2}` should pass `E2` as parameter to `\artmisc` and friends?

Comment: I have updated the questions. I have need to print each `\arttext`, `\artcolor` separately in each paragraph.

Comment: @Balaji: I've updated my solution to (hopefully) address your requirements.

Comment: The following `hyperref` link is not working. \hyperref{http://www.balaji.org/\artabbrtext/main.html} or \href{http://www.balaji.org/\artabbrtext/main.html}

Comment: @Balaji: Use `\href{http://www.balaji.org/artabbrtext/main.html}`.

Comment: I have need to update the stored variable in `hyperlink`. Example: `\def\artabbrtext{\arrayx{artabbrtext@aux}(#1)}%` `\href{http://www.balaji.org/artabbrtext/main.html}`.

Comment: @Balaji: You need to use `\url{<URL>}`, not `\href{<URL>}`.

Comment: @Balaji: So what changed in your setup that caused you to un-accept this answer?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer if your data is in an external file (data.tex).  If your data file is as follows:

```
article 1 title
article 1 short title
article 1 sub-title
article 1 color
article 1 misc value

article 2 title
article 2 short title
article 2 sub-title
article 2 color
article 2 misc value

article 3 title
article 3 short title
article 3 sub-title
article 3 color
article 3 misc value

article 4 title
article 4 short title
article 4 sub-title
article 4 color
article 4 misc value

Memoirs of a LaTeXer
Mem. LaTeXer
Nerds Gone Wild
cyan
non-fiction
```

then this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\newcounter{index}
\newcounter{rowindex}
\newcommand\arttext[1]     {\artloop{#1}{1}}
\newcommand\artshortname[1]{\artloop{#1}{2}}
\newcommand\artabbrtext[1] {\artloop{#1}{3}}
\newcommand\artcolor[1]    {\artloop{#1}{4}}
\newcommand\artmisc[1]     {\artloop{#1}{5}}
\newcommand\artloop[2]{%
  \setcounter{rowindex}{#2}
  \setcounter{index}{1}
  \whiledo{\theindex<#1}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
    \addtocounter{rowindex}{6}%
  }%
  \mydata[\therowindex]%
}
\parindent 0in
\begin{document}
\readrecordarray{data.tex}\mydata
\underline{Data for record 5:}\\
\arttext{5}\\
\artshortname{5}\\
\artabbrtext{5}\\
\artcolor{5}\\
\artmisc{5}
\end{document}
```

will read through the records to produce the following:

[image]

Comment: I think I have *Nerds Gone Wild* on one of my external drives :P